# Disable _all_ colour highlights in Vim

Tags: vim

I need to switch off all highlighting in a text file.

This is what I have tried, to no avail:

```
:syntax off
:set nohlsearch
:set syntax=
:match
:set noshowmatch
:set t_Co=0
```

Output of some "debug" commands:

```
:set syntax --> shows "syntax="
:syntax --> No Syntax items defined for this buffer
```

set t_Co=0 keeps the highlights, just switches the whole screen to black and white.

Comment: Out of curiousity, why are you trying to do this? Are you getting incorrect highlighting, or do you just find it annoying...?

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but did you try them in combination? http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_turn_off_all_colors

Comment: i am trying to do this because I can't read as well with the highlights on. Yes, I have tried all of the commands above in combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to disable spell-checking, which was enabled from a location I could not see where I was looking.